# На битриксе не работает функция CFile::MakeFileArray() - чем её можно заменить?

Tags: битрикс

```
$arLoadProductArray = Array(            
    "DETAIL_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $folder_with_pictures . $DETAIL_PICTURE),
    "PREVIEW_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $folder_with_pictures . $DETAIL_PICTURE)
    );
```

На битриксе не работает функция CFile::MakeFileArray(), на первом сайте всё хорошо, картинки в элемент инфоблока вставляются, на втором не вставляются.

**Чем функцию  CFile::MakeFileArray() можно заменить?**

Answer (score 1):

Не хватало слеша в пути, из за этого он неправильный был и функция не работала.